# Javascript xmlhttp send api requests from forms

Tags: javascript, html, rest, api, xmlhttprequest

I have a server running locally which has an in built rest api. To login through this api, we need to send username, password and organization as parameters to url localhost:8090/ehr/api/v1/login via POST method and server returns an auth token as response. when I try to do this directly without user input from form through the following code:

```
<html>
<body>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
          xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
            if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
              document.write(this.responseText);
              console.log(this.responseText);

            }
          };    
        xhttp.open("POST", "http://localhost:8090/ehr/api/v1/login", true);
        xhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
        xhttp.send("username=admin&password=admin&organization=123456");
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

It works perfectly fine and auth token is returned as json, but if I try to do the same through user form input via following code:

```
<html>
<body>
<form method="POST">
    <input type="text" name="username" id="username" placeholder="Username">
    <input type="password" name="password" id="password" placeholder="Password">
    <input type="text" name="organization" id="organization" placeholder="Organization">
    <button id="submit" onclick="login()">Let me in!</button>
    <br><br>
</form> 
<script type="text/javascript">
    function login() {
        var user=document.getElementById("username").value;
        var pass =  document.getElementById("password").value;
        var org = document.getElementById("organization").value;
        var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
          xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
            if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
              document.write(this.responseText);
              console.log(this.responseText);

            }
          };    
        xhttp.open("POST", "http://localhost:8090/ehr/api/v1/login", true);
        xhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
        var param = "username="+user+"&password="+pass+"&organization="+org;
        xhttp.send(param);
    }   
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

this code throws error

```
login.html:26 XHR failed loading: POST "http://localhost:8090/ehr/api/v1/login"
```

What is wrong with the second code and how to correct it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out myself, I just removed form tag from html and used simple input tags instead. This solved the problem maybe because forms on submission try to load a new page instead of staying on the same page, but the parameters were intended to get fetched from the original page. Which was not able to happen as new page got loaded every time submit button was clicked.

Answer (score 0):

*send your params in this way*

xhttp.send('username=user&password=pass&organization=org');